# Pig Latin Converter - need help figuring out how to find and not convert numeric elements

Tags: r, regex

I am writing a function that converts a phrase to pig Latin. However if the phrase contains a number the function needs to leave them as is, and I am having some issues finding a way to do this.

I've tried using `regmatch`, `gsub` and `which` statements and haven't figured out the best way to do this.

Here are a few things I tried out:

```
phrase <- "the 24 brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog"
```

Here is the function:

```
piglatin = function(phrase) {

  phrase2 <- tolower(phrase)
  phrase3 <- strsplit(phrase2, split=" ")[[1]]
  phrase4 <- paste(gsub("(.)(.*)", "\\2\\1ay", phrase3), collapse=" ")
  return(phrase4)

}
```

Here are my attempts to extract numbers. This needs to be inserted into the function somewhere.

```
matches <- regmatches(phrase, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", phrase))
as.numeric(unlist(matches))

x <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", phrase)  # Numbers with any number of digits
x2 <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(phrase, x)))
```

> Input: `"the 24 brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog"`
>
> Actual Output: `"hetay 42ay rownbay oxfay umpsjay veroay hetay azylay
>   rownbay ogday"`
>
> Desired output: `"hetay 24 rownbay oxfay umpsjay veroay hetay azylay
>   rownbay ogday"`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to catch numbers, it might be easier to use a couple of capture groups - first for the first letter, second for the following letters if present, and third for the following white space if present.

```
gsub("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)(\\s?)", "\\2\\1ay\\3", phrase)
#[1] "hetay 24 rownbay oxfay umpsjay veroay hetay azylay rownbay ogday"
```